# Change ArrayFire array at Index Array with repeating indexes

Tags: c++, vectorization, arrayfire

Is there a Way to Change an Array multiple times at the same Position?
When I do this:

```
float a[] = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 };
array A(6, a, afHost);
af_print(A);

float i[] = { 0, 1, 2, 2};
array I(4, i, afHost);

A(I) += 1;

af_print(A);
```

the result will be

```
A
[6 1 1 1]
1.1000
1.2000
1.3000
0.4000
0.5000
0.6000
```

instead of

```
A
[6 1 1 1]
1.1000
1.2000
2.3000    // <--
0.4000
0.5000
0.6000
```

I understand what the Problem is, but there has to be some sort of work around, like counting Index occurrences first.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it after a couple of hours.
this function splits an Array into Arrays with just unique values:

```
vector<af::array> AFSeperateToUniqueIdxBufs(const af::array& a)
{
    int count = a.elements();
    af::array aSorted;
    af::array origIdxs = af::seq(count);
    af::sort(aSorted, origIdxs, a, 0, true);

    vector<af::array> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (count > 1)
        {
            const af::array& aSortedNext = af::join(0, aSorted(af::seq(1, count - 1)), (af::constant(-1, 1)));
            const af::array& unique = aSorted != aSortedNext;
            const af::array& uniqueIdxs = af::where(unique);
            v.push_back(origIdxs(uniqueIdxs));
            const af::array& restIdxs = af::where(!unique);
            count = restIdxs.elements();
            aSorted = aSorted(restIdxs);
            origIdxs = origIdxs(restIdxs);
        }
        else
        {
            v.push_back(origIdxs);
            break;
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

After that I Loop through the Arrays and Change the original one step by step.

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    const af::array& uniqueIdxs = I(v[i]);
    A(uniqueIdxs) += 1;
}
```

If there is any better or official Way, let me know